# What exactly does: "The same property cannot be projected more than once" mean?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

There are three limitations for projection queries in google datastore, and I can't figure out exactly what the second limitation is referring to.

A few of the examples referenced seem like this does not mean you can only ever write one projection query of a given property.

Is this maybe simply saying I can't write a query like: Select A, B, A where E="e1" ?

Sorry if I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A projection query cannot have a property more than once. For example,

```
SELECT name, age, name from Person
```

would result in an error because property "name" appeared in the list two times.

Comment: Thank you kindly.  What a weird limit for google to impose, since I can't imagine why anyone would ever need to query for the same information twice like that.